# Celery not receiving tasks to run in background

Tags: python, redis, celery, amqp

I'm having an issue setting up celery to work with my flask app. I've used a barebones app to test the configuration and have found that my celery worker is started but not picking up any of the tasks like in all the tutorials. Basically, when you call the .delay() function it is supposed to take your python function and send it to celery to process in the background but instead things hang because a connection could not be made. So possibly my configuration is incorrect or there is a bug in one of the versions of software I have downloaded that I am unaware of.

Here's the contents of my requirements.txt file:

```
amqp==5.1.0
anyjson==0.3.3
async-timeout==4.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.3
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.0.4
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.4
Deprecated==1.2.13
Flask==2.0.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
kombu==5.2.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
packaging==21.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.28
pycparser==2.21
pyparsing==3.0.7
pytz==2022.1
redis==4.2.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.32
typing_extensions==4.1.1
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
Werkzeug==2.0.3
wrapt==1.14.0
yahoofinancials==1.6
```

Here's tasks.py. Note the commented out line because for some reason the celery worker doesn't launch properly without the backend specified which is also weird.

```
from celery import Celery
from time import sleep

#app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://localhost')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def reverse(myString):
    sleep(5)
    return myString[::-1]
```

The celery app starts fine in the virtual environment:

```
C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\projectFiles>..\Scripts\activate

(testApp) C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\projectFiles>celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO

 -------------- celery@DESKTOP-GHMPTB0 v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0 2022-03-31 12:07:03
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x24f8cfca1a0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.add
  . tasks.reverse

[2022-03-31 12:07:03,550: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2022-03-31 12:07:03,565: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,128: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 240 calling self.run()
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,128: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 13564 calling self.run()
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,128: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 8584 calling self.run()
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,128: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 8344 calling self.run()
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,611: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-03-31 12:07:04,642: INFO/MainProcess] celery@DESKTOP-GHMPTB0 ready.
```

And then the results of sending the function call to celery give me a connection error. This is the part that stumps me.

```
(testApp) C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\projectFiles>python
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tasks import *
>>> result = add.delay(2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 614, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\retry.py", line 45, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 615, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 680, in _connect
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 668, in _connect
    sock.connect(socket_address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py", line 119, in reconnect_on_error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\celery\backends\redis.py", line 169, in _consume_from
    self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1549, in subscribe
    ret_val = self.execute_command("SUBSCRIBE", *new_channels.keys())
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 1390, in execute_command
    self.connection = self.connection_pool.get_connection(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 1386, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 620, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 10061 connecting to localhost:6379. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

To confirm, I am running python version 3.10.4 which is an accepted version for celery.

```
(testApp) C:\Users\Owner\My Drive\Documents\Scripts\virtual_envs\testApp\projectFiles>python --version
Python 3.10.4
```

Does anyone see what is wrong? I can't really move forward in my real project if I can't get background tasks to work. I'm new to celery and trying to figure it out but am willing to switch brokers or scheduling software if I cannot make this work.

Comment: There are two major updates. Redis was not working so I replaced the backend with "rpc://" and for some reason this allowed the worker to start normally. Every time it starts now it displays every task I have sent to it but refuses to process any of them.

The second change was that my worker had to be told to use eventlets. So I installed it and added "-P eventlet" to the end. I understand that it is now switching from using a process to a simulated thread. It is not a thread because it is controlled by the app instead of the OS. I can't say I understand what is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

'connection refused', which means there was nothing listening to the IP:port you tried to connect to. you should check your Redis instance.

debugging tip: you can remove the backend parameter and test again if everything works well, you will be sure about having a problem with the Redis connection.

Answer (score 0):

try to run:

> celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO **-P solo**

or  install eventlet

> pip install eventlet

end, try to run:

> celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO -P eventlet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).